# Access the image URL of a product

Tags: bigcommerce

I am trying to get the image URL inside Edit Theme Files -> product.html

I already have some values like:
{{product.title}}, that gives me "Product name"
{{product.url}}, that gives me the URL
etc...

but no matter what i try, i can't get the URL.

The closest I got was using this: {{product.main_image.data}}
which gives me something like this:

https://cdn3.bigcommerce.com/s-8lxh1/images/stencil/%7B:size%7D/products/882/1700/RAM_VB_193_SW1__09586.1463668242.jpg?c=2

But that does not produce a image link.

Would appreciate any help or insights.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string that you're returning doesn't work because there's a "size" placeholder embedded in the URL.  You can use Stencil's getImage Handlebars helper to specify the image dimensions and return a working URL:

```
{{getImage product.main_image.data "thumbnail"}}
```

The "thumbnail" string specifies an image size that exists in your theme settings.  You can also specify a numeric size, like "200x200".  Check out the docs [here](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/handlebars-image-helpers)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks for the code snippet and for the explanation.